# 'of which' in 'to the utmost extent of which' (1906 UK)

Tags: difference, relative-pronouns

Source: p 279, *The Family*, by [Helen Bosanquet, BA in Moral Sciences (First Class; Cambridge)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helen_Bosanquet)

> "If the husband is the head of the Family", she continued, "the wife is the centre.
>   It is she who is primarily responsible for `the care of the children`;
>   to the utmost extent **of which** the family means will allow,
>   it is her ***duty to see*** they are well cared for, both physically and morally;
>   and it is generally agreed that this duty can be properly fulfilled only by personal attention.

1. Am I right that **which** 's antecedent is `the care of ...` ?

2. I can't pinpoint why, but **of which** bothers me. It feels redundant.
What would differ if **of which** were removed? Please explain?

Footnote: I encountered the above on p 28 of 296, *Understanding Housing Policy*, by B Lund.

Comment: Please include complete sentences in your questions.

Comment: @snailboat Sorry about that. I wanted to localise the question. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helen Bosanquet BA in Moral Sciences 1906 was using a verb *allow of* which [peaked around 1700](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(allow%20of)&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28allow%20of%29%3B%2Cc0), then fell off, and then enjoyed a little renaissance around 1850. It means 'to allow'.

So the clause could be rewritten:

**To the utmost extent which the family means will allow *of*, it is her duty to to see...**

**To the utmost extent *of* which the family means will allow, it is her duty to see...**

In contemporary English using *allow* instead of *allow of*:

**To the utmost extent which the family means will allow, it is her duty to see...**

Comment: FMI: See OED's II. 3. b.  http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/5460?redirectedFrom=allow

Answer (score 0):

You are right. 'of which....' refers to the 'care'

If you remove 'of which', it becomes...

> "If the husband is the head of the Family", she continued, "the wife is the centre. It is she who is primarily responsible for ***the care*** of the children; to the utmost extent the family means will allow, it is her ***duty to see*** they are well cared for, both physically and morally; and it is generally agreed that this duty can be properly fulfilled only by personal attention.

The sentence does not become clumsy. It conveys the message. `'of which'` is a part of relative clause and I think it just gives a bit more precise information removing which may not change the sentence. Said that, you *can* call that redundant *in that sentence*.

But it's not always. In some cases, it's important to 'remove' the dependency (relative clause) in order to get rid of `'of which'` or else the sentence may not look good.

> [[Source:]](https://books.google.com/books?id=KHp1kMdSJ8MC&lpg=PA137&ots=ymyMbo90-D&dq=%22Congress%20passed%20the%20statute%2C%20the%20purpose%20of%20which%20was%20to%20lower%20taxes%22&pg=PA137#v=onepage&q=%22Congress%20passed%20the%20statute,%20the%20purpose%20of%20which%20was%20to%20lower%20taxes%22&f=false) Congress passed the statute, the purpose ***of which*** was to lower taxes

In the above, there's a comma and 'of which' plays as a relative clause.

Now...

> Congress passed the statute; the purpose was to lower taxes
>   *[note that I put semicolon to make sentence independent)*.

Comment: Thanks. For want of brevity, I did only quote the first part of the sentence. But what do you mean by `there's a semicolon before ...`? I see a semicolon in my OP? Please edit my OP directly if I neglected something.

Comment: No, there's no msitake in pasting. I'm just drawing your attention that the semicolon separates those two sentences.

Comment: +1. Thanks. I ought to have quoted the entirety, as you advised. I just wanted to localise the question. Fixed now.

Comment: I edited your post minorly and apologise for any offense. Please feel free to refine or revert.

Comment: I believe this answer is a bit misleading. The issue is as straightforward as explained in TRomano's answer.