# How to dissect and parse 'to whose extent'?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, relative-pronouns

[Source:](https://books.google.com/books?id=Rehu8OOzMIMC&pg=PA182&dq=%22to+whose+extent%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UIEsVcqLC8nmsASYqoGQBA&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22to%20whose%20extent%22&f=false) p 182, *WordNet: An Electronic Lexical Database*,
by [Christiane Fellbaum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christiane_Fellbaum) PhD Linguistics (Princeton)

> Graphically, mathematical lattices can be depicted as line diagrams 
>   that represent a formal concept by a small circle. [See p 181 of the link for a picture.] For each formal 
>   g,
>   the smallest formal concept   **to whose extent** *g* belongs   is denoted by *γg*,     ...

Please correct me if I err, but 'to the extent of which' can be called a 'relative phrase', based on p 186, *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar* (2005), by Huddleston & Pullum.
My [tribulations with it](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/54693/8712)
inspired me to Google examples **'to whose extent'** for practice.

I know that as a relative determiner, [whose](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/whose)  =  of whom  or  [of] which.
The quote concerns only objects (and not persons); so **whose**  =  `of which`. Then:
**to `whose` extent**  =  **to `the` extent `of which`**.

Then how do you dissect and parse this relative phrase?

Comment: I think both of these "extent" and "intent" are used as technical terms in their mathematical context, which I believe is about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_concept_analysis.

Comment: -1 for formatting.

Comment: @snailboat What formatting would you like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For each formal g, the smallest formal concept     ***to whose extent g belongs***
>   is denoted by γg

Much more often, I hear/read "X belongs to Y", but in this sentence, *to* appears before *belongs*.  Also, *whose* is kind of functioning here as a "possessive that" for lack of a better term.

So this sentence can be rewritten like this:

> For each formal g, the smallest formal concept     ***that its extent g belongs to***
>   is denoted by yg.

So:

- Each "formal g" is associated with an "extent g" (implied).
- Extents belong to one or more "formal concepts."
- The smallest of these "formal concepts" is called *yg*.

Comment: @LawArea Please stop vandalizing answers by inserting spaces and newlines randomly.

Comment: @snailboat My edits are not intended to be random; I am just trying to accentuate the differences. They certainly are not `vandalizing answers`.

Comment: @LawArea It's vandalism.  It's not *intended* as vandalism, and I understand that.  You're trying to contribute to the site.  But that doesn't mean that making an answer harder to read with this kind of formatting is okay.

Comment: @snailboat Thanks for your understanding. I genuinely thought that the formatting and spacing simplified the comparison between the two. So I'll just ask the answerer whether this helps, as below.

Comment: @snailboat To user 'ultrasawblade': I edited your post minorly and apologise for any offense. Please feel free to refine or revert, if my formatting and spacing discommode your answer.